# Dynamic NamedValue in Azure APIM

Tags: azure-api-management

I am trying to pass on a 'NAMED VALUE' name to APIM via my logic Apps. The context is that depending on the calling partner, I need to use a specific credential for Salesforce. Refer below for the APIM policy snippet.

```xml
<!-- START Dynamic SF user identification -->
<set-variable name="nv_username" value="@(context.Request.Headers.GetValueOrDefault("nv_username"))" />
<set-variable name="nv_password" value="@(context.Request.Headers.GetValueOrDefault("nv_password"))" />
<choose>
    <when condition="@(context.Request.Headers.ContainsKey("nv_username"))">
        <set-variable name="get_tokenbody" value="@("grant_type=password&client_id={{Common-Salesforce-ClientID}}&client_secret={{Common-Salesforce-ClientSecret}}&username={{" + (string)context.Variables["nv_username"] + "}}&password={{" + (string)context.Variables["nv_password"] + "}}")" />
    </when>
    <otherwise>
        <set-variable name="get_tokenbody" value="@("grant_type=password&client_id={{Common-Salesforce-ClientID}}&client_secret={{Common-Salesforce-ClientSecret}}&username={{Common-Salesforce-Username}}&password={{Common-Salesforce-Password}}")" />
    </otherwise>
</choose>
<!-- END Dynamic SF user identification -->
```

However, when the policy runs, it does not replace the namedvalue with the actual value. For example, refer the APIM Trace below. Can you advise how I can make APIM get the actual NamedValues instead?

```json
set-variable (0.001 ms)
{
    "message": "Context variable was successfully set.",
    "name": "get_tokenbody",
    "value": "grant_type=password&client_id=<redacted>&client_secret=<redacted>&username={{Project1-Salesforce-Username}}&password={{Project1-Salesforce-Password}}"
}
```

In summary, I am trying to pass the NamedValue's name to APIM from LogicApps. The NamedValue to be used in the policy will differ based on the consumer. Hence the ask.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you just want to get rid of `{{`.
Therefore I just removed `{{` and `}}` in
`&username={{" + (string)context.Variables["nv_username"] + "}}&password={{" + (string)context.Variables["nv_password"] + "}}")" />`

The following policy returns the string either with values stored as Named Values or as the passed header values:

```xml
<policies>
    <inbound>
        <base />
        <!-- START Dynamic SF user identification -->
        <set-variable name="nv_username" value="@(context.Request.Headers.GetValueOrDefault("nv_username"))" />
        <set-variable name="nv_password" value="@(context.Request.Headers.GetValueOrDefault("nv_password"))" />
        <choose>
            <when condition="@(context.Request.Headers.ContainsKey("nv_username"))">
                <set-variable name="get_tokenbody" value="@("grant_type=password&client_id={{Common-Salesforce-ClientID}}&client_secret={{Common-Salesforce-ClientSecret}}&username=" + (string)context.Variables["nv_username"] + "&password=" + (string)context.Variables["nv_password"])" />
            </when>
            <otherwise>
                <set-variable name="get_tokenbody" value="@("grant_type=password&client_id={{Common-Salesforce-ClientID}}&client_secret={{Common-Salesforce-ClientSecret}}&username={{Common-Salesforce-Username}}&password={{Common-Salesforce-Password}}")" />
            </otherwise>
        </choose>
        <!-- END Dynamic SF user identification -->
        <return-response>
            <set-status code="200" reason="OK" />
            <set-header name="Content-Type" exists-action="override">
                <value>application/json</value>
            </set-header>
            <set-body>@{   
                var response = new JObject();
                response["tokenbody"] = context.Variables.GetValueOrDefault<string>("get_tokenbody");
                return response.ToString();
            }</set-body>
        </return-response>
    </inbound>
    <backend>
        <base />
    </backend>
    <outbound>
        <base />
    </outbound>
    <on-error>
        <base />
    </on-error>
</policies>
```

### Request with header values:

> POST https://rfqapiservicey27itmeb4cf7q.azure-api.net/sample/clone-64182/ipsum HTTP/1.1
> Host: rfqapiservicey27itmeb4cf7q.azure-api.net
> nv_username: theusername
> nv_password: thepassword

Response body with values from the header:

```json
{
    "tokenbody": "grant_type=password&client_id=lorem&client_secret=secret&username=theusername&password=thepassword"
}
```

[image]

### Request with Named Values

Configured Named values:

[image]

> POST https://rfqapiservicey27itmeb4cf7q.azure-api.net/sample/clone-64182/ipsum HTTP/1.1
> Host: rfqapiservicey27itmeb4cf7q.azure-api.net

```json
{
    "tokenbody": "grant_type=password&client_id=lorem&client_secret=secret&username=ipsum&password=pw"
}
```

[image]

Comment: I am trying to pass the NamedValue's name to APIM from LogicApps. The NamedValue to be used will differ based on the consumer. Hence the ask. Hope I made the requirement clear.

Comment: I guess this will not work

Comment: Thanks Markus for your time, do you know if this requirement can be achieved at all in Azure APIM?

Comment: You can use a custom header and based on the value can read different named values